# POST request treated as OPTIONS on beego framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go, beego

I'm using beego framework as my API framework and AngularJS on the client.
I have set all CORS setting correctly. I can do GET request. But, when i try to POST, beego treat is as OPTIONS request. It also throw a warning: `multiple response.WriteHeader calls`. what could possibly wrong?

my beego CORS setting:

```
func init() {
    orm.RegisterDataBase("default", "mysql", "root:@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/fakeapi")
    beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.BeforeRouter, cors.Allow(&cors.Options{
        AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH", "POST"},
        AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin"},
        ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    }))

}
```

My ANgularJS request

```
var transaction = $http.post(BASE_URL + "transaction", transactionData);
                return $q.all([transaction]).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

my system:
Ubuntu 14.04
beego: 1.4.2
bee: 1.2.4
angularJS: 1.3.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might because of an issue/pull request currently pending to be merged into master: [issue 912](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/912)

> Without this line everything is fine:: [router.go#L861](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/d536f5b8dce63500b16e99d7977beecee0b23262/router.go#L861)

That seems to be in line with [commit 3bb4d6f](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/commit/3bb4d6f0133dbe526e1917bebe2dc7a98ced6384) which shows:

```
// Write status code if it has been set manually
// Set it to 0 afterwards to prevent "multiple response.WriteHeader calls"
```

(and `router.go` do set a status, hence the error message)

[Commit f962457](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/commit/f96245786ae0e7b454420fb339a66cadb6676917) is supposed to solve this issue, but isn't merged yet.

---

The other [issue 904](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/904) mentions something about being unable to retrieve the Session data previously registered in the Session Engine.
Maybe [Session.on flag](https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/d536f5b8dce63500b16e99d7977beecee0b23262/config.go#L54) can help.

Comment: thanks for your response. i have delete that line  mention in commit f962475. but the error persists.

Comment: @under5hell ok, I have only found one other instance of this error involving Session (I have edited the answer). But it is more a clue than a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I handle it like that, I hope it helps

```
import (
_ "info_apoyo/routers"

"github.com/astaxie/beego"
"github.com/astaxie/beego/plugins/cors"
)

func main() {
if beego.BConfig.RunMode == "dev" {
    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.DirectoryIndex = true
    beego.BConfig.WebConfig.StaticDir["/swagger"] = "swagger"
}
beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.BeforeRouter, cors.Allow(&cors.Options{
    AllowOrigins:     []string{"*"},
    AllowMethods:     []string{"GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "PATCH"},
    AllowHeaders:     []string{"Origin", "content-type", "Access-Control-
Allow-Origin"},
    ExposeHeaders:    []string{"Content-Length", "Access-Control-Allow-
Origin"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
beego.Run()
}
```

Comment: THIS IS SHOWING ERROR with beego api
cannot use cors.Allow(&(cors.Options literal)) (value of type beego.FilterFunc) as web.FilterFunc value in argument to beego.InsertFilter

Comment: @PiyushRaj Seems you are using Beego V2 and the answer is for Beego v1